# c++ error in 2D array index

Tags: c++, arrays

I am working on a C++ program and the issue is in the below code. (NB: code has been simplified for readability but the essence is still there). In the first part i am just creating a 2D array with a few simple conditions

```
    rows= 5/2;
    cols= 4/2;

    char** array;
    if(rows%2 !=0 ){
     array = new char*[rows+1];
    }else {
         array = new char*[rows];
    }
    for(int k = 0; k < rows; k++)
    {
        if(columns%2 !=0){
            array[k] = new char[cols+1];
        }else{
            array[k] = new char[cols];
        }

    }
```

So far so good. the code works perfectly. the next part is where the issue is,

```
  for(int k = rows; k<5; k++){
        for (int l=0; l< 2; l++){
            array[k-rows][l]=Array2[k][l];            
        }
    }
```

so basically this code is just retrieving a small part of a larger array (`array2`) and inserting it into `array`. but An error keeps coming up at `array[k-rows][l]=Array2[k][l];` which says `Thread 1:Exc_BAD_ACCESS(code = 1, address = 0xe)`. (i am using xcode 7.2)

Comment: Dimensions of `Array2`?

Comment: 4 times `array`. That is not the issue. I also tested this with `array[k-rows][l]='X'` which removes any uncertainty with array2 and still the error occurs.

Comment: Why don't you step through the loop and see what the values of `rows`, `k`, and `l` are, and what the values of `array[k-rows]` and `array[k-rows][l]` are? That should help you quickly narrow down which part of the expression is going wrong and probably point to why.

Comment: `array[k-rows]` accesses out of bounds . Your array is 2x2, but `k-rows` takes values `0`, `1`, `2`  (the last of those being out of bounds). You probably want to do the `%2` check on `5` BEFORE diving it by 2.

Comment: Why don't you use (a) std::vector and (b) *one* vector of  size rows*cols. That would be considerably easier.

Answer (score 2):

With `rows= 5/2`; you set `rows` to `2`. Than you allocate 2 `rows` `array = new char*[rows];`. But you iterate from 2 to 4 `for(int k = rows; k<5; k++)` and write to rows  0 to 2 `array[k-rows][l]`. You never allocated row with index 2.

```
rows= 5/2; // now rows is 2
...
if(rows%2 !=0 ) // 2%2!=0
```

Try this:

```
rows= 5;
cols= 4;

int allocRows = ( rows%2==0 ) ? rows/2 : rows/2+1;
rows=rows/2;

int allocCols = ( cols%2==0 ) ? cols/2 : cols/2+1;
cols=cols/2;

array = new char*[allocRows];
for(int k = 0; k < allocRows; k++)
    array[k] = new char[allocCols];
```

... or this ...

```
int origRows = rows; 
rows= 5/2;
...
if(origRows%2 !=0 )
...
```

Comment: i am allocating 3 `rows` `array = new char*[rows+1];` due to the conditions in the first piece of code

Comment: @john.s Or `rows = (rows + 1) / 2; cols = (cols + 1) / 2;` instead of the `if`/`else`, since both will be positive.

Comment: @Gernot1976 the way you did it is correct, however i do want to iterate from 2 to 4, the way you solved it would iterate from 3 to 4.

Comment: would this iterate from 2 to 4? i think i still need to do the if else block since i have other stuff to put in the block